# Can't graph value in Kibana using data placed in Elasticsearch by Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a log that looks like this:

```
2014-06-12T14:59:01.120997 - MONITOR - Load [0.01] Spawn [9]
2014-06-12T15:00:01.187993 - MONITOR - Load [0.67] Spawn [7]
2014-06-12T15:01:01.292163 - MONITOR - Load [0.86] Spawn [0]
2014-06-12T15:02:01.409863 - PROVISION - [other line format]
2014-06-12T15:02:03.305833 - MONITOR - Load [0.09] Spawn [8]
```

I have logstash monitoring it and sending to elasticsearch with this input and filter (more efficient way to write this also appreciated.  I'm completely new to logstash/elasticsearch):

```
input {
   file {
       type => "load_monitor"
       path => "/var/log/load_monitor.log"
       sincedb_path => ["/opt/load_monitor"]
   }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "load_monitor" {
        grok {
            match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime} - %{WORD:montype} - %{GREEDYDATA:content}"]
        }
        if [montype] == "MONITOR" {
            grok {
                match => ["content", "Load \[%{NUMBER:load:float}\] Spawn \[%{NUMBER:spawn:int}\]"]
            }
            mutate {
                remove_field => ['content']
            }
        }
        if [montype] == "PROVISION" {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to be correct in elasticsearch via kibana (the load and spawn fields exist and are populated correctly):

```
{ 
"message":"2014-06-12T15:15:01.436632 - MONITOR - Load [0.71] Spawn [5]",
"@version":"1",
"@timestamp":"2014-06-12T22:15:02.304Z",
"type":"load_monitor",
"host":"prx01",
"path":"/var/log/load_monitor.log",
"logtime":"2014-06-12T15:15:01.436632",
"montype":"MONITOR",
"load":0.71,
"spawn":5 
}
```

When I try to create a histogram in kibana of the "spawn" value, "spawn" isn't auto-suggested and I get this error when I try to graph spawn anyway:

```
SearchParseException[
    [logstash-2014.06.12][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
    Parse Failure [
        Failed to parse source  
        [
            {
                "facets": {
                    "0": {
                        "date_histogram": {"key_field":"@timestamp","value_field":"spawn","interval":"10s"},
                        "global":true,
                        "facet_filter": {
                            "fquery":{ 
                                "query":{
                                    "filtered":{
                                        "query":{
                                            "query_string": {
                                                "query":"type: \"load_monitor\""
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "filter":{
                                            "bool":{
                                                "must":[
                                                    {
                                                        "range":{
                                                            "@timestamp":{"from":1402610796579,"to":1402611696579}
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "fquery":{
                                                            "query":{
                                                                "query_string":{
                                                                    "query":"type:(\"load_monitor\")"
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            "_cache":true
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "size":0
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

Can anyone help with this?  I suspect I have to tell elasticsearch to make the spawn field searchable somehow, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You should take a look at the logs of ElasticSearch while you make the query and paste the corresponding traces as well

Comment: The log shows this exception: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]  However, after collecting about 24 hrs of data, the histogram for "spawn" now works when I select a period of 12 hrs or less.  I think it's because I didn't originally specify ":int" in the logstash grok filter.  When I include data from before I had the ":int" specifier, I get the error.